# Java picam preview

Tags: java

I am currently trying to incorporate a temporary stream in my card panel layed out like this.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ5xp.jpg)

Where it says scan your QRCode im trying to get a stream from the picam. Here is the issue.

I dont know how i can buffer that into the Java application

I got the command i want --> "raspistill -w 200 -h 200 -q 100 -t 5", but i just dont know how this would work. This is the first time im dealing with any video stream.

As for the second part. I need that "preview" to take a picture whenever it is able to grab the QRCode. I checked both apis for the raspberry pi camera but im still lost as in for direction. I also need this buffered so i can instantly parse it into my decodeQRCode method. What component do i need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with sarxos webcam api.

```
class VideoFeed extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            webcam.open();
            boolean bool = true;
            while (bool) {
                try {
                    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
                    var = BackEnd.refund(image,type[0]);
                    lblCamera.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                    if (var[0] != null) {
                        bool = false;
                        webcam.close();
                        btnScan.doClick();
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

started it by doing

```
new VideoFeed().start();
```

With this i opted for a more general driver.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It's more like a comment. Read through [answer], thanks. Note that you have the option to delete your question, just in case you did not know.